VirtualBox Guest Additions: kernel modules and services were not reloaded
I am following this procedure to manually install and mount virtualbox guest additions on a virtualbox VM having OS Ubuntu 22.04 hosted on windows 10.
I am doing this because I have run into the error VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0X80BB0005).
What I did without encountering any error is:


sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)


restart the VM via sudo reboot.

from the VirtualBox topbar "Device" menu -> Click "Insert guest additions CD"


sudo mkdir -p /mnt/cdrom
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
cd /mnt/cdrom



but as I run
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run 

I get
mount: /mnt/cdrom: WARNING: source write-protected, mounted read-only.
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   MD5 checksums are OK. All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 7.0.12 Guest Additions for Linux  100%  
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 7.0.12 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Starting.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Setting up modules
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel 
modules.  This may take a while.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: To build modules for other installed kernels, run
VirtualBox Guest Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup <version>
VirtualBox Guest Additions: or
VirtualBox Guest Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup all
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the modules for kernel 6.8.0-40-generic.

where a problem is outlined:
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Look at /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log to find out what 
went wrong
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Running kernel modules will not be replaced until 
the system is restarted or 'rcvboxadd reload' triggered
VirtualBox Guest Additions: reloading kernel modules and services
VirtualBox Guest Additions: cannot reload kernel modules: one or more module(s) 
is still in use
VirtualBox Guest Additions: kernel modules and services were not reloaded
The log file /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log may contain further information.

so I open the log file /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log and I see
Building the main Guest Additions 7.0.12 module for kernel 6.8.0-40-generic.
Error building the module.  Build output follows.
make V=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL= -C /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build M=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j4 modules
make[1]: warning: -j4 forced in submake: resetting jobserver mode.
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0 need-builtin=1 need-modorder=1 
# cmd_mod /tmp/vbox.0/vboxguest.mod
  printf '%s
'   VBoxGuest-linux.o VBoxGuest-common.o common/string/strformatrt.o combined-agnostic.o combined-os-specific.o | awk '!x[$0]++ { print("/tmp/vbox.0/"$0) }' > /tmp/vbox.0/vboxguest.mod
# CC [M]  /tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.o
  gcc-12 -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/.VBoxGuest-linux.o.d -nostdinc -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -I./ubuntu/include -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -DKERNEL -fmacro-prefix-map=./= -std=gnu11 -fshort-wchar -funsigned-char -fno-common -fno-PIE -fno-strict-aliasing -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -fcf-protection=none -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -mindirect-branch-cs-prefix -mfunction-return=thunk-extern -fno-jump-tables -mharden-sls=all -fpatchable-function-entry=16,16 -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -fno-allow-store-data-races -fstack-protector-strong -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -ftrivial-auto-var-init=zero -fno-stack-clash-protection -fzero-call-used-regs=used-gpr -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -falign-functions=16 -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Wall -Wundef -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-format-security -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-frame-address -Wno-address-of-packed-member -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -Wno-main -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -Wno-dangling-pointer -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wcast-function-type -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-alloc-size-larger-than -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible
-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -Wenum-conversion -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -Wno-restrict -Wno-packed-not-aligned -Wno-format-overflow -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-stringop-truncation -Wno-override-init -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-type-limits -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-sign-compare -g -gdwarf-5 -Wno-declaration-after-statement -fno-pie -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling.h -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -DKERNEL -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DVBOX -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_GUEST -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DIN_MODULE -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -fsanitize=bounds-strict -fsanitize=shift -fsanitize=bool -fsanitize=enum  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"VBoxGuest_linux"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxguest"' -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_vboxguest -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.o /tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.c   ; ./tools/objtool/objtool --hacks=jump_label --hacks=noinstr --hacks=skylake --retpoline --rethunk --sls --stackval --static-call --uaccess --prefix=16   --module /tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.o
# CC [M]  /tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-common.o
  gcc-12 -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/.VBoxGuest-common.o.d -nostdinc -I./arch/x86/include -I./a

but I do not understand what has gone wrong and how to fix it.
what I have tried
I have restarted the system and redone the procedure, but the same error is raised.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled the same version of Virtualbox, started the VM, but the issue remains.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled the latest version of Virtualbox, started the VM, but the issue remains.
